# Parent component not visible

Tags: angular

In angular 2, I have a parent component that displays a child component route on click. Hence i toggle the visibility of the parent component with ngIf on click of the button. But when this parent component is itself called directly by its parent, the Oninit method doesn't toggle the parent component.
So when the parent component's parent is clicked, nothing is dispalyed. I have to first open a different component and then click the link to open the particular parent component, otherwise nothing gets displayed. Please help. In showrequest component html -

```
<table *ngIf = "flag" class="table table-bordered info-table">

</table>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In showrequestcomponent.ts -

```
ngOnInit() {
this.flag = 1;
}

toggle(){
this.flag = 0;
}
```

On clicking a button, toggle method hides the parent component and only router-outlet child component is visible.
But when I again click on a button on the parent of show-component to display showcomponent, the Oninit method doesn't fire because it has never gone outside  this component and hence nothing is displayed this time. I have to first goto some other component and then again come back to show-component to view this component.

Comment: Can you provide us some code ?

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem context might be clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case of App State Management. You should use a Single Service where the 'visiblity' state of the components are stored and in the components(Parent, child etc.), subscribe to these States via the service. Whenever a visibility state is changed, it is changed in the service and all components subscribing to these states will reflect the changes.

[Observables and Data Sharing](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2016/11/08/angular-2-and-observables-data-sharing-in-a-multi-view-application/)

**app-state.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppStoreService {

    private _parentIsVisible: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

    // Subscribe to this variable
    public parentIsVisible: Observable<boolean> = this._parentIsVisible.asObservable();

    public toggleVisibility(): void {
        this._parentIsVisible.next(!this._parentIsVisible.value);
    }
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<table *ngIf="isVisible">
//
</table>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    \\
})
export class ParentComponent {

    // use this variable in html
    isVisible: boolean;

    constructor(private service: AppStoreService ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.parentIsVisible.subscribe(res => {
            this.parentIsVisible = res;
        });
    }

}
```

**You can toggle the flag from anywhere in the code.**

```
@Component({
        \\
    })
    export class SomeComponent {

        constructor(private service: AppStoreService ) { }

        toggleVisibility() {
            this.service.toggleVisibility();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I shall try this and get back in case I have other queries.

Comment: @user9316680 - I updated according to your solution.

Comment: It works really well. Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: @user9316680 - Hey, that's great. Could you mark my answer as correct. That would help me alot too =)

Comment: Done @Shaurya Dhadwal

Comment: @user9316680 - Thankyou :)